Android webview gives net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB
Android WebView gives net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB  when loading URL tried solutions didn't help only showing on some URLs

The error net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB is related to a request that breaks CORS.
There is this Google group conversation that mentions that a change happened in Chromium:
Handle ORB network errors as DevTools issues

ORB "v0.2" changes error handling from silently injecting an empty
response to raising a network error. Since the default is to log
errors on the console this can lead to a very "spam-y" console. To
resolve this, we will always report ORB network errors
(ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB) to DevTools as an issue, and will suppress
console messages for the same errors.

I would suggest making sure that the original url that is loaded within the webview has the same domain as the url that is giving you this error.

I got the same few days ago. It seems that only happens with 206 HTTP codes ( stream) not returning the content-type header field.
Try setting that field on your server to correct one
